# How to restore HDFS blocks moved out of /dataN/dfs/dn/current directory?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Due to an unfortunate series of events, a program moved blocks from
`/dataN/dfs/dn/current/BP-XXXXXXX/current/finalized/subdirN/subdirN/blk_NNNNNNNNNN`
into 
`/tmp/blk_NNNNNNNNNN`

I don't have any logging from the program to tell where the original `subdirN/subdirN/` directory was.

Is there any way to figure out where this block should be based on fsimage file, the block file itself, or some other metadata?

I was able to restore some blocks by looking for the corresponding *.meta file, but there are still some holes. Replication saved me from the worst of it, but I'm still missing 5 "mission critical" files I'd like to try and recover.

From `hdfs fsck /` I can tell what the missing blocks are, and what HDFS files they belonged to, but I can't tell where in the blockpool they should have been placed.

`hdfs fsck / -delete` is NOT a solution. I don't want to delete things, I want to try my hardest to recover the files, because I HAVE the blocks. I just don't know where they go.

`$ hdfs version
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.4.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing to fix this. This wont work in all cases, but it worked in mine.

I took advantage of the fact that the input file separator would be the "line input record separator" and that the blocks in hadoop could be concatenated with the missing block. Order of the data doesn't matter for me, only that all the lines are there.

I simply retrieved all the blocks for the file (including the one no longer in hdfs that was moved to a new location), concatenated them all together. Deleted the file from HDFS and did an `hdfs -put` of the contaminated file to restore the contents.

Not perfect, but it was effective. This saved me from having to reverse engineer anything, and also proved the easiest way to restore the data.

Thanks for the help. I'm sure there is useful information in here for the next person with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it possible to do the restore manually, but you can try.

The subdirs are calculated in the: `DatanodeUtil.idToBlockDir(...)` using the following code:

```
int d1 = (int)((blockId >> 16) & 0xff);
int d2 = (int)((blockId >> 8) & 0xff);
String path = DataStorage.BLOCK_SUBDIR_PREFIX + d1 + SEP + DataStorage.BLOCK_SUBDIR_PREFIX + d2;
```

If the files were moved manually, the fsimage might still contain the block ids, use `hdfs oiv` command to convert `fsimage` to `XML` and get the blockIds by deleted file names.

Comment: If you decide to reverse engineer the DataNode directory layout by looking at the code like this, please make sure to look at source code that matches the version you are running (mentioned here as CDH 5.4.4).  We have changed the block ID-to-directory mapping several times in different versions of Apache Hadoop.

Comment: @ChrisNauroth well since I am not a commiter I am unaware of those details :P (the code is from 2.6 though, but from Hadoop github, not from Cloudera distro).

Comment: no worries.  :-)  I just wanted to put a warning out there in case someone running a different version discovers this question later.

Comment: This almost worked. I used python to take the blockId part of the filename to do the bit shifting to find subdirs. The block is in the right place, but after `hdfs fsck` is still marked corrupted and underreplicated. I'm assuming it has to do with the missing .meta file.

Any ideas on how to regenerate the .meta?

Comment: I believe that it is `ReplicaInfo`(more concretely `FinalizedReplica`) object which were stored into your meta files. But I am not 100% sure, maybe @ChrisNauroth could comment on this.

Comment: @Serhiy , this is a pretty complicated process, and I don't recommend trying to reimplement it.  Apache Hadoop 2.8.0 and 3.0.0-alpha2 released a new command that recomputes and saves the .meta file from a given block file.  Development of this command was tracked in [HDFS-11009](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-11009).  Your best bet is probably trying to adapt that patch.  Once again I'll put out the warning that it's very important to match up code changes with your currently running version of Hadoop for compatibility.